# what is the best way to test params in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Well, I have a params hash like this:

```
params = { :q => { :id_eq => "" } }
```

What is the best way to test if `id_eq` is blank?
I'm currently using `if params[:q] && params[:q][:id_eq].blank?` but it seems a lot of duplicated code.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if params.fetch(:q, {id_eq: true})[:id_eq].blank?
```

---

Comparison between the OP's original code and other answers. So far, my answer is the only one that gives the correct result.

```
params = { :q => { :id_eq => "" } }

params[:q] && params[:q][:id_eq].blank?         # => true (OP)
params.fetch(:q, {id_eq: true})[:id_eq].blank?  # => true (my code)
params[:q].try(:[], :id_eq).blank?              # => true (Marek Lipka)
params.try(:values_at, :q).first[:id_eq].blank? # => true (mbratch old)
params[:q][:id_eq].blank? rescue false          # => true (Doydle)
params.fetch(:q,{})[:id_eq].blank?              # => true (Stefan)
params.try(:[], :q).try(:[], :id_eq).blank?     # => true (mbratch new)

params = { :q => { :id_eq => "foo" } }

params[:q] && params[:q][:id_eq].blank?         # => false
params.fetch(:q, {id_eq: true})[:id_eq].blank?  # => false
params[:q].try(:[], :id_eq).blank?              # => false
params.try(:values_at, :q).first[:id_eq].blank? # => false
params[:q][:id_eq].blank? rescue false          # => false
params.fetch(:q,{})[:id_eq].blank?              # => false
params.try(:[], :q).try(:[], :id_eq).blank?     # => false

params = {}

params[:q] && params[:q][:id_eq].blank?         # => nil   (falesy value)
params.fetch(:q, {id_eq: true})[:id_eq].blank?  # => false (falesy value)
params[:q].try(:[], :id_eq).blank?              # => true  # Wrong
params.try(:values_at, :q).first[:id_eq].blank? # => true  # Wrong
params[:q][:id_eq].blank? rescue false          # => true  # Wrong
params.fetch(:q,{})[:id_eq].blank?              # => true  # Wrong
params.try(:[], :q).try(:[], :id_eq).blank?     # => true  # Wrong
```

For the purpose of conditional, the difference between `nil` and `false` would not matter, but getting `true` instead of `nil` is surely wrong.

Comment: I'm still confused. Using `fetch` seems to be more code than before, and why shouldn't I use `try()` ?

Comment: Because if you use `try`, it will give the wrong result. It will return `true` when `params` does not have the key `:q`.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. But still I think this way you are saying is way more hard to read than the way I'm currently using. I wonder if there are any consensus in this matter :)

Comment: That is subjective. If you define `{id_eq: true}` as a constant in advance, then the code would be shorter.

Comment: Although this question seems to have no "correct" answer, but a lot of different points of view, I will mark this one as the answer because it is a great reference and has the tests for the proposed solutions.

Comment: @renatojf Thanks for marking it. I agree that my answer may not necessarily be an improvement over yours, but it is the only correct answer among all the answers given.

Comment: Why am I downvoted? At least, it is the only answer that gives the correct result.

Comment: This is a poor solution, not only does it involve more code than @renatojf's original post, it's much harder to understand at first glance.

Answer (score 4):

There is no better way than how you're already doing it. (At least in my opinion.) Relying on exceptions is a bad idea and anything else is significantly less legible.

Answer (score -1):

`rescue` is always an option:

```
if (params[:q][:id_eq].blank? rescue false)
```

Comment: Is there something about rails that I'm missing? I tested it in irb and it worked fine

Comment: Not sure what you mean by working fine. Did you compare it with the OP's code?

Comment: Yes. If `params[:q]` is nil then you get an exception, which triggers the `rescue` to return `false`